# How do I get a user's boost date

Tags: discord.js

Does anyone know how i can get a user's boost date?
I'm making a command where the user can see the day of your boost, I already tried to get the nitro signature start date, but I specifically need the boost date

Answer (score 0):

You can see since when a user boosts a server by reading the premiumSince property from a guild member.

### Solution

This can look like this:

`client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).members.cache.get(member_id).premiumSince`.

Just replace `guild_id` with your server id and `member_id` with your the user id. **Note: The premiumSince property is only avalible for a guild member that is why you have to get the guild first and then the user!**

### Date Conversion

The line of code should give you an output like this `1995-12-17T03:24:00` to convert the date take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) post about JavaScript's Date() function.